# PHP form not sending an email.Get thank you page but no email

Tags: php, html, webforms

I have a HTML web form on my website with a php script. When hit submit, thank you page loads however the details submitted do not go off to the recipient.

Website is hosted on 1and1

http://www.evolutionroofingltd.co.uk/contact.html

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

contact.php

```
<?php
/* Set e-mail recipient */
$myemail  = "gregtwardochleb@hotmail.co.uk";

/* Check all form inputs using check_input function */
$yourname = check_input($_POST['yourname'], "Enter your name");
$email    = check_input($_POST['email']);
$phone  = check_input($_POST['phone'], "provide phone number");
$comments = check_input($_POST['comments'], "Write your comments");

/* If e-mail is not valid show error message */
if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
{
show_error("E-mail address not valid");
}

/* If URL is not valid set $website to empty */
if (!preg_match("/^(https?:\/\/+[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/i", $website))
{
$website = '';
}

/* Let's prepare the message for the e-mail */
$message = "Hello!

Your contact form has been submitted by:

Name: $yourname
E-mail: $email
URL: $website

Comments:
$comments

End of message
";

/* Send the message using mail() function */
mail($myemail, $phone, $message);

/* Redirect visitor to the thank you page */
header('Location: thanks.htm');
exit();

/* Functions we used */
function check_input($data, $problem='')
{
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
{
    show_error($problem);
}
return $data;
}

function show_error($myError)
{
?>
<html>
<body>

<b>Please correct the following error:</b><br />
<?php echo $myError; ?>

</body>
</html>
<?php
exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: The big mystery here is where the `mail` function comes from.

Comment: @joepd PHP has a built-in mail() function

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious about the use of `$phone` for the subject line - but unless there are funny characters in there I don't think that is the issue.

I'd suggest that at the top of the script you turn on error reporting ( ie: `error_reporting( E_ALL )` etc ) and then attach an `if` condition to the mail function to see what you get, ie:

```
$res=mail( $myemail, $phone, $message );
if( !$res ) show_error( print_r( error_get_last (),1 ) );
```